# Convert an array of string to array of db ref

Tags: mongodb

I'm new on MongoDB  and I want to convert an array of strings to an array of DbRef

I have the following structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ecd4defc786165efea7638f"),
"ready" : false,
"dzones" : [],
"targets" : [ 
    "5ecd4d2afe92844481b25bd4", 
    "5ecd4d23fe92844481b25bd3"
],
"data" : {},
"name" : "banner1",
"creationDate" : ISODate("2020-05-26T17:11:38.093Z"),
"tags" : [],
"_class" : "Ad"
```

}

targets elements are referencing another document and i want to convert them to DBRef elements.

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by dbref?

Comment: @ngShravil.py Sorry i mean DbRefs
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation

Comment: Not sure you *really* want to do that.  Per the docs, DBRefs are not automatically resolved by the drivers; you would still have to take the material and issue a second call to fetch it.  Just turn them into `ObjectId` and use `$graphLookup` to produce the linkage.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti i made it work. You will find bellow the way i did it. 
i'll be glad if you give me your opinion

Comment: I was doing lot of research, using aggregation, map the `targets` array to array of `{'$ref': 'collectionName', '$id': ObjectId('xyzxyz'), '$db': 'dbName'}`. But, I was not able to make it as Mongo doesn't allow to create fields starting with `$`. So, I concluded that it cannot be done with the normal Mongo queries. But, that's great, you have done it.

Comment: can you please vote the answer as usefull. Thanks

Comment: My opinion is that DBRefs are sort of ... unhelpful.   They are nothing more than a struct that holds _id, the collection name as a string, and optional DB name as a string.   Neither the drivers nor the engine "do anything" with this.   But some people might think they can do "autolookups" or get referential integrity something as a result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cursor = db.Ads.aggregate(
    [
        { $project:
                { target_ids:
                        {
                            $map:
                                {
                                    input: "$targets",
                                    as: "target",
                                    in: "$$target"

                                }

                        }
                }
        }
    ]
)

var bulkUpdateOps = [];

cursor.forEach(doc => {
    const { _id, target_ids } = doc;

    var targets = [];
    doc.target_ids.forEach(id => {
        targets.push(new DBRef('Targets', new ObjectId(id)))
    });

    bulkUpdateOps.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { _id },
            "update": { "$set": { targets } },
            "upsert": true
        }
    });

    if (bulkUpdateOps.length === 1000) {
        db.Ads.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
        bulkUpdateOps = [];
    }
});

if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) {
    db.Ads.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
}
```